# field replace on odoo using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-9

I've tried Odoo 9 and want to replace the "Total" field = amount_total with a new field which is the result of some addition of field content (sum_of_total) with XPath expression but it's failing and not returning any result.
Here is my XML code :

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="purchase_order_form_training1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.form1</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="amount_tax" position="after">
                    <field name="down_payment" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field':'currency_id'}"/>
                </field>
                <xpath expr="form1/sheet/page/group/field[@name='amount_total']" position="replace">
                    <field name="sum_of_total"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The odoo log didn't show me any syntactical error. Can anyone help me to identify the root cause?

Refer below to understand how sum_of_total is getting initialized

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class purchase_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order"

    @api.one
    @api.depends('down_payment', 'amount_total')
    def get_total_after_dp(self):
        dp = self.down_payment
        tot = selt.amount_total
        tota = tot + dp
        self.sum_of_total = tota

    sum_of_total = fields.Float('Total Amount',
                                    compute='get_total_after_dp')

    down_payment = fields.Float('Down Payment')
```

Comment: What exactly did the error message tell? Try <xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_total']" position="replace">
                    <field name="sum_of_total"/>
                </xpath>

Comment: I think the error is from `form1` in the expr. Try as Manu suggested. Use `//field[@name=...]` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `form1` in the purchase order form view. 
try this:

```
<xpath expr="form/sheet/notebook/page/group/field[@name='amount_total']" position="replace">
     <field name="sum_of_total"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: You could also shorted this slightly: `//field[@name='amount_total']`. You're searching for a field directly using its name, so you shouldn't need to provide a full path.

Answer (score 1):

Just add double forward slash for direct search but if there many items with same name in same view you should use full path .

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_total']" position="after">
      <field name='sum_of_total'/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.